# Use c# code to provide user name for Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics

Tags: c#, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I recently started to explore Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics on my website. the basic functions have been working fine. Then I want to add the user name so I can track that in Google Analytics. I did some research and they say I need to add user name to the data layer, I tried to implement below but the website will not load and shows an error code of 500. the Com.Datatypes.Common.System.UserSessionData.Username is c# code and I'm pretty sure it is working correctly and my doubt is the syntax I use for data layer (dataLayer.push) is wrong, but I'm not sure why.

Here is the html code in my index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script language="CS" runat="server">

protected string GetSessionUserName()
{
    return Com.Datatypes.Common.System.UserSessionData.Username;
}
</script>   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

dataLayer.push({
 'user_id': <%GetSessionUserName()%>
});
</script>
...

</head>
```

I tried to debug and if i replace  'user_id': <%GetSessionUserName()%> with  'user_id': 'John' then on the google tag manager I can successfully see user_id coming through correctly. It's after I use the function to retrieve the userName that the issue start to show. But I can't hard code the user name to 'John'.

Comment: Not really familiar with CS but maybe add a quote between the echo part like : `'<%GetSessionUserName()%>'`